# Livewire V3 not working after upgrading from MIX to VITE

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vite, laravel-livewire

I am working on a project and needed to install the Mix plugin alongside Vite. after that I have removed Mix and Install Vite again and I come to the issue of livewire not working.

for example:

```
 #[Validate('required|string|max:255')]
    public $selectedCategory;
    #[Validate('required|string|max:255')]
    public $selectedDoctor;

    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.appointment-booking');
    }

    #[Computed()]
    public function categories()
    {
        return Category::all();    
    }

    #[Computed()]
    public function doctors()
    {
        return Doctor::where('category_id',$this->selectedCategory)->get();   
    }
```

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
  <select class="form-select border-0" style="height: 55px;" name="selectedCategory"     wire:model.live='selectedCategory'>
  <option value="" selected>Select Department</option>
      @foreach ($this->categories as $category)
           <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->title }}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
  @error('selectedCategory') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>


<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
   <select class="form-select border-0" style="height: 55px;" name="selectedDoctor" wire:model.live='selectedDoctor'>
       <option value="" selected>Choose Doctor</option>
       @foreach ($this->doctors as $doctor)
       <option value="{{ $doctor->id }}">{{ $doctor->name }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
   @error('selectedDoctor') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>
```

The error:

Using $this when not in object context

```
@foreach ($this->categories as $category)

  <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->title }}</option>

@endforeach
```

Note: The old livewire files are working fine, but the new ones are not working!

Comment: Is the view fragment containing @foreach included somehow from a non-livewire view?